# Putting sensitive credentials into userdata attribute of AWS instance

Tags: windows, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, powershell

I'm injecting sensitive credentials into userdata and not sure if this is safe.

I'm using the userdata attribute to run a script that joins the instance to a domain when it comes online

And passing the creds in like this:

```
$ADUser = 'me'
$ADPassword = 'Pass'
$ADPassword  = $ADPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$ADCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ADUser, $ADPassword

Add-Computer -Credential $ADCred -DomainName mydom.local -NewName testing
Restart-Computer -force
```

I'm using the `New-EC2Instance` cmdlet to start it and pass this script in as userdata

Could my credentails show up in error output in aws logs? or somewhere else? The credentails are secure before they are injected into the PS command, am concerned about where it lives in AWS.

Comment: User data is available in the AWS Console and from within the instance to anyone who has a shell or can get your app to make and output a HTTP request (`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`). IMO, it's a risky spot to put anything sensitive.

Comment: Hmm Is there a way I could have it purged after it runs?

Comment: Per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html you'd have to stop the instance to do so.

Comment: Can I edit userdata with with the powershell cmdlets?

Comment: It's probably not recommended, but if your account is appropriately secured and you use IAM to set up access appropriately then I doubt there will be much impact. If anyone breaks into your AWS account they get your domain password, which is bad, so you'd need two factor authentication for all access - console and API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put credentials and other sensitive data in the User Data script.

The AWS documentation stresses:

> **Important**
>
> Although you can only access instance metadata and user data from within the instance itself, the data is not protected by cryptographic methods. Anyone who can access the instance can view its metadata. Therefore, you should take suitable precautions to protect sensitive data (such as long-lived encryption keys). You should not store sensitive data, such as passwords, as user data.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Instead, create an IAM Role for EC2 Instances and give it permissions to execute what needs to be executed. Then assign the IAM role to the EC2 instance.

Comment: "it cannot be assigned later", actually this is possible.

Comment: At the time of writing, it could only be assigned at launch time. I have updated the answer to adjust for functionality changes.